# In Devops, how do you put Test Plan suites in Alpha Order Like in MTM?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure Devops we have many suites under one test plan. I am trying to order the suites alphabetically but am unable to. Is there a way to sort or order the suites/folders?

Looks similar to this:

Organization > Project > Test Plans > TestPlanName

```
 >TestPlanName
      >TestSuite1
      >TestSuite4
      >TestSuite7
      >TestSuite2
      >TestSuite11
      >TestSuite3
      >TestSuite9
      >TestSuite6
      >TestSuite8
      >TestSuite10
      >TestSuite5
```

I would like the suites to be in alpha order but can't see how to sort them at all... This is not an issue in MTM and when we review the suites there, they are in order. It's only in the Azure Devops that they are not.

I've looked through all the settings I can find and nothing touches the order.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. It's probably wise to contact Azure support. Have you done that?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues, for questions that have specific answers related to the azure-devops tag, the community is usually faster at answering than logging to the developer community.  A lot of the product team will answer here and they also link to it from their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/#feedback)

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop a test suite:

[image]

Comment: That's an option. We have a little over 200 suites currently, so it may be time consuming, but it's better than nothing...